# How to Order management in ecommerce module for Orchard CMS

Tags: module, e-commerce, orchardcms

I'm developing an e-commerce module for **Orchard CMS**.
I cannot make decision for creating **Order** and **OrderDetail** as **ContentPart** or simple table.
What is best solution for implementing order section?
Please Help me and say your opinion and reasons.

Answer (score 2):

As Bertrand points, I think that you only should make a ContentType entity that will take advantage from the Orchard's feature (or for faster admin development if  isn't a heavy app). Be aware that the ContentItems are too abstract, so it has some penalisation (just use the debugger and you will see what happens).

Furthermore, are you aware that Orchard already has an ecommerce module? Try to follow DRY, and if you don't want to use it, at least,  you should see the source code (Nwazet.ecommerce).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I saw all e-commerce module of orchard (and code of them). They are not match to sale cycle in my country.

Answer (score 1):

It really comes down to whether or not you want your Orders to be content items or not.  As content items they can benefit from using features designed for use with Orchard. Some examples include indexing, built-in permissions, and dynamic type definitions.

There are sometimes reasons when you wouldn't want a model to be a content item.  Maybe, for example, you might want to move your order system out of Orchard at some point.  Not relying on Orchard's built-in features for order management might make that process easier.

Personally, I like to default to using content parts because I really like the Orchard architecture and I feel that it saves me a lot of time with boilerplate code.  I only switch to using bare models after discovering a clear reason to do so.

Comment: And I have the reverse approach: I won't make something a content type unless there is a clear reason why it should be one. In this case, I don't see the point of making order and order detail content types.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I checked code of all ecommerce module for orchard for example sipkeschoorstra tutorial, nwazet.commerce by Bertrand Le Roy and ems and csurieux, DarkSky Commerce, ...
But i saw very different approach about order management and others therefore, I'm confused.

Comment: Hello @bertrand-le-roy
Can you please tell me an example of clear reason for making part about specific type in ecommerce module (order, invoice, payment, ...)?
built-in permissions, faster admin development and ... isn't reason for you?

Comment: You can find lots of pros and cons explained here: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/447532